# UITableView Delegate functions execute before data source can be retrieved from database - SWIFT?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to load some data into `UITableView` from a database but the delegate functions used to populate the `tableView` executes and returns an empty table before I have had a chance to retrieve the data to be displayed in `tableView`?

Please can someone advise?

Here is my code:

```
 var arrayOptions = [String]()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("MenuOptions viewDidLoad ...")

    getArrayOfOptionsForMenu()
}

 private func getArrayOfOptionsForMenu(){
    // Get list of menu options and populate array
    // Construct parameters to send to server

    var parameter = [String:String]()
    parameter["getoptions"] = "formenu"

    let optionsURL = LabBookAPI.getCredentialsUrl(parameters: parameter, targetUrl: "getOptions.php?")
    var request = URLRequest.init(url: optionsURL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        if let jsonData = data{
            do{
                let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])
                print("jsonObject: \(jsonObject)")

                guard
                    let myArray = jsonObject as? [String] else{
                        print("data not in [String] format")
                        return
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                    self.arrayOptions = myArray
                    print("self.arrayOptions.count: \(self.arrayOptions.count)")
                }
            }catch let error{
                print("print error: \(error)")
            }
        }else if let requestError = error{
            print("error detail: \(requestError)")
        }else{
            print("unexpected error")
        }
    }// End task
    task.resume()
}// End of function

 /* DELEGATE FUNCTIONS */

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("numberOfRowsInSection self.arrayOptions.count: \(self.arrayOptions.count)")
    return self.arrayOptions.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print("cellForRowAt self.arrayOptions.count: \(self.arrayOptions.count)")
    let cell = UITableViewCell.init(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: "optionCell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.arrayOptions[indexPath.row]
    print("self.arrayOptions[indexPath.row]: \(self.arrayOptions[indexPath.row])")
    return cell
}
```

My console:

> viewDidLoad ...  NSDataPDFDocument: nil  MenuOptions viewDidLoad ... 
>   MenuOptions viewWillAppear ...  numberOfRowsInSection
>   self.arrayOptions.count: 0  numberOfRowsInSection
>   self.arrayOptions.count: 0  numberOfRowsInSection
>   self.arrayOptions.count: 0  jsonObject: (
>        Profile,
>        "Sign out"  )  self.arrayOptions.count: 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is fetched from the network which takes some time to do. Rendering the TableView doesn't need to wait around.

We call these longer tasks Asynchronous tasks, they run in the background and the app continues doing other things until we get a response.

All you need to do is tell the TableView to reload the data when you get your response

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.arrayOptions = myArray
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

**EDIT:**

I think you are using a UITableViewController which already contains a UITableView property, so you can use self.tableView. If you aren't using a UITableViewController then you need to create an outlet and set `self.tableView.dataSource = self` and `self.tableView.delegate = self`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reload table data:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
    self.arrayOptions = myArray
    print("self.arrayOptions.count: \(self.arrayOptions.count)")
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: is tableView an outlet?

Comment: There is no difference, only you should have reference to tableView